# How to write type combined a value of a type depending on 2-modes simply in TypeScript type?

Tags: typescript, types

I write codes of type combined a value depending on mode property: it is following

```js
// type definition
type Mode = {mode: 'number' | 'string'};
type ObjectDependsOnMode<T extends Mode> = T & {
  value: T["mode"] extends 'number' ? number : string
}

// example
type TestMode = {
  mode: 'number',
  pokemon: 'pikachu',
}
const testObject: ExtendedObjectDependsOnMode<TestMode> = {
  mode: 'number',
  pokemon: 'pikachu',
  value: 25,
}
```

I think it is awful complex.
I am wondering and writing redundant codes.
What do we simply and readable write codes to do?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There is nothing inherently wrong with this approach; it depends on your use case.

Comment: Thx for your comment.
I try to make a type-guard of input-form, and post this question.
If a input form of type has text,  type of it's value is string.
If this has number, it is number.